# How to show asynctask value in activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I wan't to display values in an activity using async tack . The code for the async task is:

```
private class BackgroundGetSignal extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private TextView name;
    //private TextView latitudeField;
    //private TextView longitudeField;
    //private TextView placeName;

    Double lat;
    Double longit;
    String addre;
    MyService myService;
    private Intent i;
    private Context context;

    public BackgroundGetSignal(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String[] o) {
        myService = new MyService();
        if (myService.canGetLocation()) {
            lat = myService.getLatitude();
            longit = myService.getLongitude();
            addre = myService.getAddress();
        }
        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        latitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);
        placeName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLocation);

        latitudeField.setText(lat.toString());
        longitudeField.setText(longit.toString());
        placeName.setText(addre);

    }
}
```

this was how I called it:

```
new BackgroundGetSignal(this).execute();
```

But the application is crashing. Please can someone tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: put the error logcat for your isuue.

Comment: Your posted code is not correct: TextViews are commented out. 
To give you a hint on howto perform well with AsyncTask: use **Callback interfaces** to pass the computed value in `onPostExecuted` and implement those in the AsyncTask executing class to fetch that passed value.

Comment: what is the exception you got?

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you should do is give try catch in your onPostExecute() method, and move the ui update codes to the try block.  Because there is a chance for excepion if the activity is not in foreground when the time of onPostExecute() execution.  If you post the crash log, it will be helpful for a detailed analysis about the issue.